# space efficient storage of binary data in IndexedDB

Tags: indexeddb

When storing a bunch of binary harddrive to Indexeddb, for space and speed considerations, is it best to write the data as Uint8Array, Blob, or would base64 perform as well?  I have 200-500 mb of binary data, originally in base64 that I am storing.